# IE-10 Cursor position when set focus on textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I have a problem in IE -10(window -7 SP-1) when set focus on a text box. my cursor position at the beginning in text-box. how can i set position End of text-box value.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hcYTT/230/)
I am try j-query code for this problem --

```
var input = $("#txt1"); // textbox Id

var len = input.val().length;

input[0].focus();

input[0].setSelectionRange(len, len);
```

[TRY WITH JQUERY CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Du7T/)

WITH JQUERY problem is resolved but why cursor set beginning in IE-10(window -7 SP-1)?

And any any other solution for this.

Comment: It works for me in IE10. I load the fiddle and the cursor is at the end of the input. -- Never mind, I just realized you're asking a different question than I thought.

Comment: second fiddle also worked for me, but First Fiddle not work in IE -10 for windows 7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322665/4770754

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an implementation choice on the part of the browser. I can't find anywhere in the HTML spec where it says where the cursor should be positioned when a text input gains focus. If you use the mouse to give an input focus, the cursor is at the clicked position in IE10, Firefox and Chrome, but absent a click event, the browsers seem to do their own thing - Chrome, for example, appears to select the entire contents of the input.

Comment: chrome does not select the entire content of the input. At least not these days? Anyways good answer. this is probably relevant, though :https://stackoverflow.com/a/31322665/4770754