# put cursor at end of text input's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So, currently I have a text-input-field with a value that is also autofocused.

On page load, the value is selected / highlighted. Is there a way I can put the cursor at the end of the value text instead of highlighting it in javascript or CSS?

Here is a js fiddle where the autofocused text's value is highlighted: http://jsfiddle.net/TaGL5/

Here is the HTML code: `<input type="text" value="value text" autofocus />`

Comment: onfocus="this.value = this.value;"

Comment: onfocus "this.value = this.value" will assign existing value to textbox, it's like you typed that text and so you have cursor at end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This works for me

```html
<input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="this.value = this.value;"/>
```

Comment: Just to update, this either no longer works in FF, or never did.  In the current version of FF, it selects the entire text, it does not place cursor after.

Comment: I found this answer helpful and works just fine cross multiple browsers: stackoverflow.com/a/19568146/936468

Comment: Does not work in FF (2022)

Answer (score 45):

Upgrade to @harsha's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2345915/183181)

I found that to make solution work with Firefox,
we need temporary reset value to "not-equal of value", then set it back

```html
<input type="text" autofocus value="value text" onfocus="var temp_value=this.value; this.value=''; this.value=temp_value" />
```

Comment: @vol7ron *"chenosaurus's method"* :D

Comment: I'm (quite new to) Spring boot and using it. Seemed I needed to use this method to get desired effect.

Answer (score 8):

Use Jquery for this:

```js
$(function() {
      var input = $("#txt1");
    var len = input.val().length;
    input[0].focus();
    input[0].setSelectionRange(len, len);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt1" value="Lorem" style="width:400px;" />
```

But some browsers don't support `enter code here` property, in which case use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").focus(function(){
        if (this.setSelectionRange)
        {
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).val($(this).val());
        }
   
});

$("#search").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="search" type="text" value="mycurrtext" size="30" name="search" />
```

This question already exist on stackoverflow:

[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376713/set-mouse-cursor-at-the-end-of-the-block-of-text/17376746#17376746)

[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430038/ie-10-cursor-position-when-set-focus-on-textbox-using-jquery)

Comment: It's a little bit of an overkill to use a thirdparty library for such an easy task

Answer (score 8):

Use this, its nice work for me...

```
<input type="text" name="txt" value="value text" autofocus="" onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length);">
```

OR add this line to your input element

```
onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length);"
```

Comment: I can confirm this works perfectly. I am using Brave (based on chromium)

Answer (score 4):

You can add this parameter to your text input field:

```
onmouseover="this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length);"
onfocus="this.setSelectionRange(this.value.length,this.value.length);"
```

NB: Works well under [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org) in 2017.

Comment: works perfect in FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Select element by class or id, then focus, and then re-insert value.

```html
<input type="text" class="element-to-autofocus" value="Some existed text" />
<script>
  temp_el = document.querySelector('.element-to-autofocus');
  temp_el.focus();
  temp_value = temp_el.value;
  temp_el.value = '';
  temp_el.value = temp_value;
</script>
```