# how to put input box cursor at end of text

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a number in input field on button click and set the cursor position at the end of text. this should happen every time when the button is clicked.

```
<input id="input"></input>
<button onclick="addnumber()">add</button>
addnumber(){

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [put cursor at end of text input's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780756/put-cursor-at-end-of-text-inputs-value)

Comment: @lusc i have tried this code but this doesnt work with button click

Answer (score 1):

JS code :

```
let input = document.getElementById('input')
function addnumber() {
  input.focus(); 
  var val = this.input.value; 
  input.value = ''; 
  input.value = val;
}
```

HTML code:

```
  <input id="input">
  <button onclick="addnumber()">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="input"></input>
<button onclick="addnumber()">add</button>
    
<script>
    function addnumber() {
        const myInput = document.getElementById('input');
        const textLength = myInput.value.length;

        myInput.focus();
        myInput.setSelectionRange(textLength, textLength);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this code is working but  first the cursor goes at the starting position of input text then comes to the end of text. i want it to stay at the text end only

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input')
function addnumber() {
  input.value=69
  input.focus()
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button onclick="addnumber()">add</button>
```